# How to compare unicode with string in python

Tags: python

I try to compare value after encode base64 with string. But `encode64` does not equal to  `Uy6qvZV0iA2/drm4zACDLCCm7BE9aCKZVQ16bg80XiU=` Why does not it equal ?

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(b'Test')
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
encode64 = hex_dig.decode('hex').encode('base64')
print(encode64)
if encode64 == 'Uy6qvZV0iA2/drm4zACDLCCm7BE9aCKZVQ16bg80XiU=' :
    print("Hello")
```

Output

```
Uy6qvZV0iA2/drm4zACDLCCm7BE9aCKZVQ16bg80XiU=
```

It does not print Hello.

Comment: `encode64` contains a newline, compare it with `encode64.strip()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a '\n' in the end of encode64 variable.
You can do

```
if encode64.strip() == 'Uy6qvZV0iA2/drm4zACDLCCm7BE9aCKZVQ16bg80XiU=' :
    print("Hello")
```